# Rails routes edit , new, destroy. How to translate in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use route_translator gem to translate routes. It works perfect.
The URL looks like:

```
domain.com/pl/kategoria/edit
```

How can I translate `edit` to `edycja` in Polish.

Regards Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without the gem. If you have categories resources in your routes:

```
scope(path_names: {edit: 'edycja' }) do
  resources :categories, path: 'kategoria'
end
```

which will yield

```
GET     /kategoria   to the index action
POST    /kategoria   to the create action   
GET     /kategoria/:id   to the show action
GET     /kategoria/:id/edycja   to the edit action
```

etc...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html  for more details on this.